# How should I secure stops against clear acrylic sheet in a half wall?

Tags: walls, woodworking, framing

I just built a half wall (sort of) with acrylic sheet in my basement to partition my server equipment from my woodworking area to keep my electronics more sawdust free. The top half of the wall is a piece of acrylic that sits in a groove in the top and right studs. I have some leftover pine board that I want to use to frame around the inside edges of the acrylic.

How would I go about securing the pine board to each other on either side of the acrylic? I want to do this so it takes the bow out of the acrylic. I was thinking a screw with a wingnut on the opposite side of the acrylic. Also, any other ideas for finishing this wall?

[image: plexiglass half wall]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off anchoring each piece of trim to the wall or sill. The plexiglass will then be sandwiched between two rigid surfaces. Putting a bolt through the plexiglass won't provide any benefit over what the trim pieces already give.

Comment: This is correct. You might also use some foam tape (weatherstipping) between the stops and the acrylic to reduce rattling and improve the seal. (I weep for your servers. :) )